# Icon in ListSelectionDialog

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to use `ListSelectionDialog.class` to create popup dialog enabling user to choose multiple projects. I want possibilities to be displayed with project icons decorated with another icon in top right. Code I'm using is as follows,

```
ListSelectionDialog dialog = new ListSelectionDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(),
projects.keySet(), ArrayContentProvider.getInstance(), 
new LabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public Image getImage(Object element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ????;
    }
},
"Choose projects to evaluate");
```

But I don't know what to put in return directive, `new Image(pathToGif)` works when I give non-relative path on my disk which is useless as it should work on many machines. And how do I add decorations?

Comment: Ok, `... .imageDescriptorFromPlugin(pluginid,pathToGIf).createImage(null)` seems to work fine, but I still miss decorations

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list contents are `IProject` values (or something that can adapt to `IProject`) you can use

```
WorkbenchLabelProvider.getDecoratingWorkbenchLabelProvider()
```

to get the standard decorating label provider for workbench objects.